# Show $|t|\leq \pi \Rightarrow |e^{it}-1|\geq 2|t|/ \pi$

Tags: inequality

I would like to show that show $|t|\leq \pi$ implies $ |e^{it}-1|\geq 2|t|/ \pi$. I tried to proof it geometrically but without success.

Comment: $|e^{it}-1|=2|\sin(t/2)|$, for $0<t<\pi/2$ try to prove $2/\pi < \sin(x)/x$.

Comment: Are you sure you mean $|t|\le \pi$?

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, I do.

Comment: ah, stupid me. Did not read careful enough.

Answer (score 3):

Factoring $\mathrm e^{\mathrm it}-1$ in the LHS as $2\mathrm i\,\mathrm e^{\mathrm it/2}\sin(t/2)$ whose modulus is $2\,|\sin(t/2)|$, and using the fact that the sine function is odd, one sees that it is enough to prove that $u(x)\geqslant x$ for every $x$ in $(0,1)$, where $u(x)=\sin(\pi x/2)$.

But $u(0)=0$, $u(1)=1$, and $u$ is concave on $(0,1)$ (as shown by the sign of $u''$, say), hence its graph on $(0,1)$ lies above its chord between the points $(0,u(0))$ and $(1,u(1))$. This is the desired inequality.